# Looping in bash from Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, cp

i need to write a Makefile that compiles each .cpp in current directory in .so file (with flags -shared -fPIC) and copyies .so file into "../../dir/" directory without ".so" extension.

For example, if filename is "div.cpp" i need to compile it into "div" and copy to ../../dir/.

Answer (score 1):

`find` is a fairly useful way of batch-commanding multiple files but it only carries the full filename around which means, when used in the `-o` argument it would generate `file.cpp.so`. But we can clean up after that.

```
find -maxlevel 1 -iname '*.cpp' -exec g++ -shared -fPIC -o {}.so {} \;
rename 's/cpp\.so$/so/i' *.cpp.so
cp *.so ../../dir
```

Comment: Output is: g++ fatal error no input files

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add the filename on the end of the command. I've fixed it now.